# Blocking IOError when using django + uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, logging, uwsgi

I am getting an error when there are too many requests coming to my application. Previously we did not notice so much issues, but recently we have seen that we get the error:

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking



 print(ServDHCPRelay,"ServDHCPRelay")
  File "/apps/netadc3/.venvs3/netadc3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "/apps/netadc3/.venvs3/netadc3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "/apps/netadc3/.venvs3/netadc3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "/apps/netadc3/.venvs3/netadc3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "/apps/netadc3/.venvs3/netadc3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "/apps/netadc3/.venvs3/netadc3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "/apps/netadc3/.venvs3/netadc3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "/apps/netadc3/.venvs3/netadc3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 196, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.flush()
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking
```

The error happens on print statements.

We upgraded from python3.6 -> rh-python3.8 recently and we are using django 3.2!
uWSGI version 2.0.20

Comment: It looks like it is a capacity issue with the output stream. Try reducing the log output, then errors may be gone.

Comment: Not sure how to reduce the log output as it very dynamic in nature. It increases/decreases depending on the number of live requests that come in. I increased the `buffer-size` in uwsgi and added `wsgi-disable-file-wrapper = true`. Lets see if that helps.